Using Swift, how can I intercept a request for an online image and serve a local image instead?
I've made a game using web technologies, and for the iOS version I am using a webview to display it to users.
While it is working, I'd like to intercept requests to external assets and serve bundled assets instead for performance reasons.
The most straightforward implementation for me seemed to be using a WKWebView and setting a custom url scheme handler using setURLSchemeHandler on the WKWebViewConfiguration. For some reason, I couldn’t get https to work as the second argument of setURLSchemeHandler (forURLScheme). I ‘hacked’ my way through and came up with the following code which doesn’t seem to crash but isn’t working properly either.
App.swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct App: App {
   var body: some Scene {
       WindowGroup {
           ContentView()
       }
   }
}

ContentView.swift
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
   // External = random prefix since https is not working
   @State private var urlString = "external://example.com/"
  
   var body: some View {
       WebView(urlString: $urlString)
           .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
   }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
   @Binding var urlString: String
  
   func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
       let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
       webConfiguration.preferences.isElementFullscreenEnabled = true
      
       let schemeHandler = CustomURLSchemeHandler()
       // external = random string since https is not working
       webConfiguration.setURLSchemeHandler(schemeHandler, forURLScheme: "external")
      
       return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
   }
  
   // Load the URL when the view appears or the URL changes
   func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
       if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
           let request = URLRequest(url: url)
           uiView.load(request)
       }
   }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
       ContentView()
   }
}

CustomUrlSchemeHandler.swift
import WebKit

class CustomURLSchemeHandler: NSObject, WKURLSchemeHandler {
   let resources: [[String: String]] = [
       ["path": "dist/audio/ambient/action_2.mp3", "mime_type": "audio/mpeg"],
       ["path": "dist/fonts/Fontin-Bold.ttf", "mime_type": "font/ttf"],
       ["path": "dist/img/backgrounds/2_titlescreen_921x1.webp", "mime_type": "image/webp"]
   ]
  
   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, start urlSchemeTask: WKURLSchemeTask) {
       guard let url = urlSchemeTask.request.url else {
           urlSchemeTask.didFailWithError(NSError(domain: "CustomURLSchemeHandler", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Invalid URL"]))
           return
       }
      
       // Remove the "external://" prefix
       let httpsURLString = url.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "external://", with: "https://")
      
       // Iterate through resources to find a matching path
      for resource in resources {
          if let path = resource["path"], url.absoluteString == "https://example.com/" + path {
              // Serve the local resource
              if let localFilePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: (path as NSString).lastPathComponent, ofType: nil),
                 let localFileData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: localFilePath)) {
                  let response = URLResponse(url: url, mimeType: mimeType, expectedContentLength: localFileData.count, textEncodingName: nil)
                  urlSchemeTask.didReceive(response)
                  urlSchemeTask.didReceive(localFileData)
                  urlSchemeTask.didFinish()
                  return
              }
          }
      }
      
      
       // no match, load the data from httpsURLString
       if let httpsURL = URL(string: httpsURLString) {
           let session = URLSession.shared
           let task = session.dataTask(with: httpsURL) { (data, response, error) in
               if let error = error {
                   print(error)
                   urlSchemeTask.didFailWithError(error)
               } else if let data = data, let response = response {
                   let mimeType = response.mimeType ?? "application/octet-stream"
                   let urlResponse = URLResponse(url: httpsURL, mimeType: mimeType, expectedContentLength: data.count, textEncodingName: nil)
                  
                   // Send the response and data back to urlSchemeTask
                   urlSchemeTask.didReceive(urlResponse)
                   urlSchemeTask.didReceive(data)
                   urlSchemeTask.didFinish()
               }
           }
           task.resume()
       } else {
           urlSchemeTask.didFailWithError(NSError(domain: "CustomURLSchemeHandler", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Invalid URL"]))
       }
   }

   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, stop urlSchemeTask: WKURLSchemeTask) {
       // Handle the cancellation of the URL scheme task if necessary
   }
}

I haven't even been able to test if serving local assets even work, because even if there a no matches found with the code above, the response is really slow and it seems to break certain stuff (by the looks of it, CSS files?).
I feel like I have tried all options out there but I feel like I'm completely stuck. To make matters worse, my server is starting to struggle because of all the people constantly retrieving all the image and audio assets that make up my game.
Does anyone know how to intercept all requests to external assets and serve bundled assets instead (if they exist)?
Thanks in advance.

Use a URLProtocol subclass, just as one does when mocking the network?

@matt thanks for your response. I have looked it up but I am not sure how to implement this together with a webview. I tried using WKURLSchemeHandler to intercept requests made by WKWebView and then to use a custom URLProtocol to handle the request but I cant get setURLSchemeHandler to work with "https" as its second parameter. Could you provide a reference to an example?

I feel like there should be lots of examples on SO. Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141516/how-to-intercept-networking-calls-rest-in-ios-using-nsurlprotocol Just search on "https NSURLProtocol", I think you can find something.
